# docker jenkins dsl pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

Hi guys i'm trying to create a pipeline with docker and jenkins and i'm getting the following error while executing `npm install` inside the container

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 1001:1001 -w 
/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SistacLabAPI -v /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SistacLabAPI:/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SistacLabAPI:rw -v /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SistacLabAPI@tmp:/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SistacLabAPI@tmp:rw jorgebo10/slapi:jenkins-SistacLabAPI-125 cat
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[SistacLabAPI] Running shell script
+ pwd
/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SistacLabAPI
[Pipeline] sh
[SistacLabAPI] Running shell script
+ ls -l
total 280
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1001 1001    316 Jul 26 23:06 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1001 1001   1331 Jul 26 19:27 Gruntfile.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1001 1001  11357 Jul 26 19:27 LICENSE
drwxrwxr-x 4 1001 1001   4096 Jul 26 19:27 app
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1001 1001    926 Jul 26 19:27 app.js
drwxrwxr-x 3 1001 1001   4096 Jul 26 19:27 config
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001   4096 Jul 27 15:29 jorge
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 240093 Jul 27 15:28 npm-debug.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1001 1001   1348 Jul 26 19:27 package.json
drwxrwxr-x 2 1001 1001   4096 Jul 26 19:27 public
[Pipeline] sh
[SistacLabAPI] Running shell script
+ hostname
61162ea48f0b
[Pipeline] sh
[SistacLabAPI] Running shell script
+ node -v
v4.4.7
[Pipeline] sh
[SistacLabAPI] Running shell script
+ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-92-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! path /.npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/.npm',
npm ERR!   parent: 'sistacLabAPI' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SistacLabAPI/npm-debug.log
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop 61162ea48f0b6044cf3b1b9d763d1b098b21af87b152901c64610df4b0060c22
$ docker rm -f 61162ea48f0b6044cf3b1b9d763d1b098b21af87b152901c64610df4b0060c22
```

My jenkins file has the following content

```
node('docker') {
    git url: 'https://github.com/jorgebo10/SistacLabAPI.git', branch:'development'

    docker.build("jorgebo10/slapi:${env.BUILD_TAG}").inside {
        sh "pwd"
        sh "ls -l"
        sh "hostname"
        sh "node -v"
        sh "npm install"
    }

    input '¿Deploy to production?'

    stage 'Production'
}
```

Any clue on what could be happening? it seems that running npm install as user 1001 is not good.

Thanks,
Jorge

Comment: how is this related to the [tag:jenkins-job-dsl] tag?

Comment: Well its related to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Pipeline+Plugin which is an extension to jenkins-job-dsl i guess, im new on this. If you think this tag is not appropiate i can change it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. While the _Pipeline_ plugins also use a DSL, it's yet another DSL compared to the one of [_Job DSL_](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin). I removed the tag to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743201/npm-install-fails-in-jenkins-pipeline-in-docker/42957034)

just wrap your stage with:

```
withEnv(['HOME=.']) {
... 
...
}
```