# npm install fails in jenkins pipeline in docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, ember.js, npm, jenkins-pipeline

I'm following a tutorial about Jenkins pipeline and I can get a "hello world" working under at node 6.10 docker container.

But, when I added a default EmberJS app (using `ember init`) to the repo and attempt to build that in the pipeline, it fails when running npm install (because of directory access issues). The Jenkinsfile can be seen here: https://github.com/CloudTrap/pipeline-tutorial/blob/fix-build/Jenkinsfile

The error message printed by the build is (which is installed locally and run using `java -jar jenkins.war` on a Macbook, not relevant but included just in case) is:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.12-moby
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /.npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/.npm',
npm ERR!   parent: 'pipeline-tutorial' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Note: I would like to *not* run `npm install` as root / sudo.

UPDATE: I have been able to make some progress as follows:

I found the command that Jenkins uses to build using the container from the logs:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
$ docker run -t -d -u 501:20 -w /long-workspace-directory -v /long-workspace-directory:/long-workspace-directory:rw -v /long-workspace-directory@tmp:/long-workspace-directory@tmp:rw -e
```

So when the docker image runs, it's work directory is a `/long-workspace-directory` (it's really a cryptic looking jenkins workspace path) and the user id is 501 (group id 20), etc. The user doesn't have a name (which is apparently breaking other things not related to this question).

1. Changed agent to use a Dockefile:

   ```groovy
   agent {
     dockerfile {
       filename 'Dockerfile'
       args '-v /.cache/ -v /.bower/  -v /.config/configstore/'
     }
   }
   ```
2. Specify `args '-v ...'` for creating volumes for the directories npm install / bower needs.

Comment: `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` try this hint.

Comment: ordinarily, you do not run `npm install` as root; it's considered really poor form; i'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Please take a look at [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: I'm not installing any global dependencies. i use nvm extensively at work and for our existing ci setup.

Comment: i think I'm using the image incorrectly. the node image is for running​a node server application, not running a series of build commands.

Comment: thinking i need to create a user or something; using `USER myuser` command in dockerfile

Comment: i'm starting to make some progress by changing NPM's cache directory to be inside the workspace directory; when the build runs in docker, jenkins does some fancy things that appear to mess up anything outside the work dir.

Comment: Or you can change the folder permissions from inside your Dockerfile like [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin/blob/d95e89a8ea41318f95dc472d7a313f5a46eb8813/Dockerfile.build#L44)

Comment: Sounds like this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43818327/627727

Answer (score 81):

Adding the environments and setting the Home to '.' solves this as below.

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'node:8.12.0' } }
    environment {
        HOME = '.'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clone') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master',
                    credentialsId: '121231k3jkj2kjkjk',
                    url: 'https://myserver.com/my-repo.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "npm install"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, magic! This solved it for me too, thanks. I suppose npm depends on the `HOME` variable which isn't set by Jenkins.

Comment: the environment can be set in single stages, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 37):

from https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/blob/master/Jenkinsfile

```
docker.image('openjdk:8').inside {
    /* One Weird Trick(tm) to allow git(1) to clone inside of a
    * container
    */
    withEnv([
        /* Override the npm cache directory to avoid: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm' */
        'npm_config_cache=npm-cache',
        /* set home to our current directory because other bower
        * nonsense breaks with HOME=/, e.g.:
        * EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.config'
        */
        'HOME=.',
    ]) {
            // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need to set `HOME=.` because the `npm_config_cache` is `$HOME/.npm`, so in this case it will be `./.npm` instead of `/.npm`

Comment: I can confirm that just setting 'HOME=.' is enough

Comment: For completeness `environment { HOME="." }` fixes the problem for Jenkins declarative syntax.

Comment: I can confirm that just setting 'npm_config_cache=npm-cache' is enough as well

Answer (score 19):

Having wasted a whole day on this issue, I found simply adding the following as an environment variable at the agent stage using the Pipeline Editor removed the problem.

```
'npm_config_cache=npm-cache'
```

Comment: I am using yarn and have the same problem. Do you know how to solve it for yarn?

Comment: how to use this config?

Answer (score 14):

When Jenkins runs the stage in Docker agent it usually sets `HOME` to image `WORKDIR` value (usually root dir `/`), but the Jenkins user does not have write permissions in this directory, that's why `npm` cannot create its cache directory `~/.npm`. To solve this you need either to override `HOME` or the location of [npm's cache directory](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#cache) by setting `NPM_CONFIG_CACHE` variable:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            reuseNode true
            image 'node:16.15'
        }
    }

    environment {
        // Override HOME to WORKSPACE value
        HOME = "${WORKSPACE}"
        // or override npm's cache directory (~/.npm)
        NPM_CONFIG_CACHE = "${WORKSPACE}/.npm"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'npm run build'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing `NPM_CONFIG_CACHE` to the docker image finally fixed it, this was a maddening problem. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Wanted to just provide a bit more detail, in short the accepted answer works but that I'm new to Docker and wanted to get a better understanding and figured i'd share what i found.

So for our jenkins setup, it starts containers via

```
docker run -t -d -u 995:315 -w /folder/forProject -v /folder/forProject:/folder/forProject:rw,z ...
```

As a result this container is running as user `uid=995 gid=315 groups=315`

Since the image I was using (circleci/node:latest) doesn’t have a user with this UID/GID, the user will not have a “home” folder and will only have permission on the mounted volume.

When NPM commands are called it will try using that users home directory (for cache) and since that user wasn’t created on the image, the home directory gets set to `/`  (default for linux?). So to get NPM to work correctly we simply point the containers HOME environment variable for the user to the current folder via the Jenkins file

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('NPM Installs') {
      agent {
        docker {
            image 'circleci/node:latest'
        }
      }
      environment { HOME="." }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Thus giving the user the ability to create the required `.npm` folder in `/folder/forProject/.npm`

Hopefully this is helpful to someone and if you see something that i got wrong please let me know :D

Answer (score 2):

I add the same issue. I solved it using the `root` user to run the Docker image:

```
node {
    stage("Prepare environment") {
        checkout scm
        // Build the Docker image from the Dockerfile located at the root of the project
        docker.build("${JOB_NAME}")
    }

    stage("Install dependencies") {
        // Run the container as `root` user
        // Note: you can run any official Docker image here
        withDockerContainer(args: "-u root", image: "${JOB_NAME}") {
            sh "npm install"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After this you have to delete all files created under root user or jenkins will fail next jobs because of permissions conflict inside the workspace directory.

Comment: plus using root in containers is a bad security practice

Answer (score 2):

You can override the user that Jenkins runs the docker container with, for example here I override with the root (userid:groupid is 0:0):

```
docker { 
    image 'node:8'
    args '-u 0:0'
}
```

You can spot the current user in the `docker run` parameters in the console output.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, the core of the problem for us was, that the user in the Container and the User running the Jenkins node had different UIDs.
After changing the UID+GID of the user in the container (and changing
ownership of the users home-directory) to match
the user running the build node npm would behave normal.

This might also happen if the Home-Directory of the container-user is not writeable.

Code in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN usermod -u <uid of buildnode> <container user> && \
    groupmod -g <gid of buildnode> <container user group> && \
    chown -R <container user>:<container user group> /home/<container user>
```

As the Workspace is mounted into the container it will already belong to the
UID. When running the container through the Jenkinsfile the UID and GID of
the container user are set automatically to match the buildnode. But the home directory will still have its original owner.

Now the node_modules will be placed in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that inside the container I was user jenkins instead of root. I got there by setting `whoami` inside the container and got error like `cannot determine user 111` (which happens to be jenkins). So I did the following:

```
stage('Run build') {
        webappImage.inside("-u root") {
            sh "yarn run build"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this configuration work for me.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:6-alpine'
            args '-p 3000:3000 -p 5000:5000'
            args '-u 0:0'

        }
    }
    environment {
        CI = 'true'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install --unsafe-perm'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/test.sh'
            }
        }
        stage('Deliver for development') {
            when {
                branch 'development' 
            }
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver-for-development.sh'
                input message: 'Finished using the web site? (Click "Proceed" to continue)'
                sh './jenkins/scripts/kill.sh'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy for production') {
            when {
                branch 'production'  
            }
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/deploy-for-production.sh'
                input message: 'Finished using the web site? (Click "Proceed" to continue)'
                sh './jenkins/scripts/kill.sh'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this solved the problem

```
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node:10-stretch'
                    args '-v /home/jenkins/.ssh:/home/jenkins/.ssh:ro -u 0'
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using maven to build the project and which indeed was running the frontend-maven-plugin which is responsible for calling the npm install
So npm install was breaking with error:
path /.npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

I changed it to
**npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache**

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can install `nvm` on the fly before building, in a local directory with `NVM_DIR` without setting it as global dependency :

```
mkdir -p node_dir
export NVM_DIR=$(pwd)/node_dir
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash
source $(pwd)/node_dir/nvm.sh
nvm install 7
nvm use 7
```

The new locations are :

```
$ which node
~/someDir/node_dir/versions/node/v7.7.2/bin/node

$ which npm
~/someDir/node_dir/versions/node/v7.7.2/bin/npm
```