# npm install fails in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

I've created a docker images to be able to run node >= 7.9.0 and monogodb for testing in Jenkins. Some might argue that testing with mongodb is not correct approach but the app uses it extensively and I have some complex updates and deletes so I need it there.

Docker file is under dockerfiles/test/Dockerfile in my github repo. When using the pipeline syntax the docker images is built successfully but I can't do sh 'npm install' or sh 'npm -v' in the steps of the pipeline. The docker images is tested and if I build it locally and run it I can do the npm install there. sh 'node -v' runs successfully in the pipeline and also sh 'ls'.

Here is the pipeline syntax.

```
pipeline {
  agent { dockerfile { dir 'dockerfiles/test' } }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
           sh 'npm install'
        }
    }
  }
  post {
      always {
        echo 'I will always say Hello again!'
      }
  }
}
```

I get this error: ERROR: script returned exit code -1. I can't see anything wrong here. I've also tested with other node images with the same result. If I run it with a node slave I can do the installation but I do not want to have many different slaves with a lot of setups for integration tests.

And here is the dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_CODENAME | cut -d= -f2)/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl && \
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash - && \
apt-get install -y nodejs && \
apt-get install -y mongodb-org


RUN mkdir -p /data/db
RUN export LC_ALL=C
RUN groupadd -g 1000 jenkins && useradd -u 1000 jenkins -g jenkins

EXPOSE 27017

CMD ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
```

Comment: `npm install` is a local command. Try using `dir` in your Jenkinsfile to select the directory you want that command to run from.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks, but I'm in the right dir. When doing ls I can see my package.json and source files.

Comment: My guess is that there is not a valid user in the container and your `npm install` requires a valid user and home directory, and since Jenkins runs the container as the Jenkins user those may not exist. Your `npm install` may use SSH (or other things) that require a valid user and home directory but those may not exist in your Dockerfile. There is [JENKINS-38438](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38438) for the user problem.

Comment: @mkobit Thanks! but I've set the user to Jenkins in my docker file do this is not the case

Comment: can you post a minimal Dockerfile that causes your issue?

Comment: @mkobit I've read the jira issue a couple of times but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. If I start the container the same way jenkins pipeline does I can do the install. docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000

Comment: can you possibly get the console log from a failed build and post it here?

Comment: @burnettk The only thing I'm getting is script returned exit code -1. When doing an npm -v the version is in catch block message. very weird

Comment: dang, you could see if the issue replicates on a fresh jenkins (`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
`). this is what i did. you do have to add a slave that can run docker. if you can't replicate it there, upgrade everything on your main jenkins and start deleting plugins? :D

Comment: @Edgesoft any luck with this problem ? Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: @EmmanuelSys Yes, we rebuild a Jenkins plugin to get it to work

Answer (score 3):

Found a workaround to a similar problem.

**Problem**

- Jenkins running a pipeline job
- This job is running commands inside a debian slim container
- All commands are failing instantly with no error output, only a `ERROR: script returned exit code -1`
- Running the container outside docker and executing the same commands with the same user is working as it should be

Extract from Jenkinfile :

```
androidImage = docker.build("android")
androidImage.inside('-u root') {
    stage('Install'){
        sh 'npm install' // is failing with generic error and no output
}
```

**Solution**

Found the answer on Jenkins bugtracker : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35370 and on [Jenkins Docker Pipeline Exit Code -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835347/jenkins-docker-pipeline-exit-code-1)

My problem was solved by installing the procps package in my debian Dockerfile :

```
apt-get install -y procps
```

Comment: ran into same issue installing procps fixed

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your setup as faithfully as I could. I used your Dockerfile and Jenkinsfile, and here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "minimal",
  "description": "Minimal package.json",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "*"
  }
}
```

It failed like this for me during npm install:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/jenkins'
```

I updated one line in your Dockerfile to add `--create-home`:

```
RUN groupadd -g 1000 jenkins && useradd -u 1000 jenkins -g jenkins --create-home
```

And the build passed. Kudos to @mkobit for keying in on the issue and linking to the jenkins issue that will make this cleaner in the future.

Comment: Thanks for this but it didn't help my issue.

Comment: I have never had a EACCES problem.