# Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I was trying to run a local Jenkins Pipeline using a Jenkinsfile for a nodejs app using node:6-alpine image (default) using a build.sh script that use call npm install then I got the following permission error

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/.npm',
npm ERR!   parent: 'my-app' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77
Jenkins running locally

I tried sudo npm install but same error. I also tried modifying docker image argv to -u root:sudo -p 3000:3000 same error

```
Jenkins file image: 
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:6-alpine'
            args '-p 3000:3000'
        }
        environment {
            HOME = '.'
        }
    }
```

build.sh script 
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Error message: npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'

Expected result: create docker container with port 3000 exposed and nodejs app running on localhost:3000

Actual result: Permission error inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer in a similar thread here: [npm install fails in jenkins pipeline in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743201/npm-install-fails-in-jenkins-pipeline-in-docker)

In my case solved it by using:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        image 'node:13-alpine'
    }
    environment {
        npm_config_cache = 'npm-cache'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```