# npm install error for Jhipster CI-CD jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jhipster, npm-install

I am trying to use jhipster ci-cd to create Jenkins pipeline.

But when I am running the jenkins pipeline in Jenkins server, I am getting following error.

Note : My jenkins server is a Jenkins instance running on Ubuntu EC2 instance [ NOT DOCKERISED JENKINS ]

Attaching the Jenkinsfile for reference.

Jenkinsfile.txt

```
./mvnw -ntp com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:npm
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.jhip.poc:jhipprojectmono >--------------------
[INFO] Building Jhipprojectmono 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.8.0:npm (default-cli) @ jhipprojectmono ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jhipprojectmono
[INFO] npm ERR! correctMkdir failed to make directory /.npm/_locks
[INFO] npm ERR! code EACCES
[INFO] npm ERR! syscall mkdir
[INFO] npm ERR! path /.npm
[INFO] npm ERR! errno -13
[INFO] npm ERR!
[INFO] npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
[INFO] npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
[INFO] npm ERR!
[INFO] npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
[INFO] npm ERR! sudo chown -R 111:115 "/.npm"
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.723 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-19T14:33:40Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.8.0:npm (default-cli) on project jhipprojectmono: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 243 (Exit value: 243) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

---------- Jenkins file --------

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node {
    stage('checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    //gitlabCommitStatus('build') {
    gitlabCommitStatus {

        docker.image('jhipster/jhipster:v6.5.1').inside('-e MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=./"') {
        //docker.image('openjdk:8').inside('-u jhipster -e MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=./"') {

            stage('path') {
                sh "pwd"
                sh "ls -ltr"
            }
            stage('check java') {
                sh "java -version"
            }

            stage('clean') {
                sh "chmod +x mvnw"
                sh "./mvnw -ntp clean"
            }
            stage('nohttp') {
                sh "./mvnw -ntp checkstyle:check"
            }

            stage('install tools') {
                sh "./mvnw -ntp com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:install-node-and-npm -DnodeVersion=v12.13.0 -DnpmVersion=6.13.0"
            }

            stage('npm install') {
                sh "./mvnw -ntp com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:npm"
            }

            stage('backend tests') {
                try {
                    sh "./mvnw -ntp verify"
                } catch(err) {
                    throw err
                } finally {
                    junit '**/target/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml'
                }
            }

            stage('frontend tests') {
                try {
                    sh "./mvnw -ntp com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:npm -Dfrontend.npm.arguments='run test'"
                } catch(err) {
                    throw err
                } finally {
                    junit '**/target/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml'
                }
            }

            stage('packaging') {
                sh "./mvnw -ntp verify -Pprod -DskipTests"
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.jar', fingerprint: true
            }
        }

        def dockerImage
        stage('publish docker') {
            // A pre-requisite to this step is to setup authentication to the docker registry
            // https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#authentication-methods
            sh "./mvnw -ntp jib:build"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the error message?

Comment: From the error it seems that your jenkins is running with a user that has / as home directory, this is why it requires sudo rights to write to ` /.npm` So I would say that your jenkins server is badly configured

Comment: I understand that .. this is user privilege issue .. So for temporary solution, i did full RWX permission to .npm folder. My expectation was .. in that case it should not have write permission issue .. but still it was giving same issue ..

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try to add

```
    environment {
        HOME = '.'
    }
```

Ref: [npm install fails in jenkins pipeline in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743201/npm-install-fails-in-jenkins-pipeline-in-docker)