# Jenkins: "sh npm i ..." not working in docker agent

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, npm, npm-install

#### Intention

I am trying to build a very simple declarative `Jenkinsfile` that is based on the latest `node` docker image. I want to install the dependencies for the `Node.js` app by calling `sh 'npm install ...'` in the `Jenkinsfile`. Installing with `npm` from the Docker container without Jenkins works like a charm, but not when using Jenkins Pipeline.

*Jenkinsfile*

```
pipeline {
   agent { 
       docker {
           image 'node:latest'
       }
   }
   stages {
      stage('Install Dependencies') {
         steps {
            sh 'npm -v' // sanity check
            sh 'ls -lart' // debugging filesystem
            sh 'npm i axios' // this leads to the error
         }
      }
   }
}
```

*Console Log in Jenkins*

```
+ npm install axios
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /.npm
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1962192188:58041779 "/.npm"
```

I assume it has to do something with the privileges in the mounted volume from Jenkins and/or the user with which the Docker container ist started from:

#### What I tried

1. `args '-u root'` in the Docker code block in the Jenkinsfile. This works but I doubt this is how this should be solved.

   ```
   docker {
       image 'node:latest'
       args '-u root'
   }
   ```
2. `sudo chown -R 1962192188:58041779 "/.npm"` as proposed in the error message. But this leads to:

   ```
   + sudo chown -R 1962192188:58041779 /.npm
   /Users/<user>/.jenkins/workspace/pipe@tmp/durable-664f481d/script.sh: 1: 
   /Users/<user>/.jenkins/workspace/pipe@tmp/durable-664f481d/script.sh: sudo: not found
   ```
3. Define a layer `RUN npm install axios` in the `Dockerfile`. This works, but out of curiosity I want to know why I cannot invoke this directly in Jenkinsfile instead.

   ```
   FROM node:latest

   RUN npm i axios
   ```

Comment: This post solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743201/npm-install-fails-in-jenkins-pipeline-in-docker#43264045

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best way to solve this issue is by using one of the following methods (inspired by [npm install fails in jenkins pipeline in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743201/npm-install-fails-in-jenkins-pipeline-in-docker#43264045)). All three will end up changing the default directory of `.npm` (i.e., npm's cache) to the current working directory (which is the Jenkins Job's workspace mapped to the Docker container).

### set ENV variable HOME to current working directory

**Declarative Pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'node:latest'' } }
    environment {
        HOME = '.'
    }
    ...
```

**Scripted Pipeline**

```
docker.image('node:latest').inside {
    withEnv([
        'HOME=.',
    ])
    ...
```

### use the additional argument `--cache` to change the location of the `.npm` folder when calling `npm install`

```
npm install --cache npm_cache <optional:packagename>
```

### set the environment variable `npm_config_cache` used by npm before calling `npm install`

**Declarative Pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'node:latest'' } }
    environment {
        npm_config_cache = 'npm-cache'
    }
    ...
```

**Scripted Pipeline**

```
docker.image('node:latest').inside {
    withEnv([
        'npm_config_cache=npm-cache',
    ])
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after trying so many things. It seems Jenkins will map the workspace directory to the docker container.

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    environment {
        HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}"
    }
...
```